# How to raise multiple ValidationError on Django?

Tags: django, validation, django-rest-framework

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError

def to_representation(self, request_data):
    raise ValidationError({
        'field_name': ["Field not allowed to change"]
    })
```

In the example above how can I throw multiple validation errors? I want to throw them as dicts to show at the respective fields.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You throw one ValidationError with multiple fields errors inside:

```
    raise ValidationError({
        'field_name_1': ["Field not allowed to change"],
        'field_name_2': ["Field not allowed to change"],
    })
```

Django 3.0+ style should follow [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/#raising-multiple-errors):

```
raise ValidationError([
    ValidationError('Error 1', code='error1'),
    ValidationError('Error 2', code='error2'),
])
```

Comment: I get `NameError: name '_' is not defined`

Comment: '_' is usually used for translations: `from django.utils.translation import gettext as _`

Comment: this is what i am getting in DRF. expected the error string instead of the error dict
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "[ErrorDetail(string='message', code='invalid')]"
    ]
}

Comment: Actually this example is for Form Validation, it does not work for Serializer Validation

Answer (score 6):

I do not recommend validating every single field inside only one function. What you should do instead is use one function to validate one field, it is way easier and simpler. If you want to do multiple validations you can find the documentation for handling multiple errors at [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/#raising-multiple-errors). The documentation shows the example below:

```
# Good
raise ValidationError([
    ValidationError(_('Error 1'), code='error1'),
    ValidationError(_('Error 2'), code='error2'),
])

# Bad
raise ValidationError([
    _('Error 1'),
    _('Error 2'),
])
```

And here is an example of mine:

```
def validate_field(value):
    errors = []

    if len(value) > 50:
        errors.append(ValidationError(
            'Error message'
        ))
    if not value.isalpha():
        errors.append(ValidationError(
            'Error message'
        ))

    if errors:
        raise ValidationError(errors)
```

Comment: Hey @friedteeth If I specify field name in the second condition along with global error `errors.append(ValidationError({'item_url': 'Item with this item url already exists.'}))` this error is still shown on top and not at the field. why??

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the django admin, you can also use `add_error()`.

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error

```
class DatForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        age = cleaned_data.get('age')  # IntegerField on your model.
        mood = cleaned.data.get('mood')  # CharField on your model. 

        if age and age < 10:
           self.add_error('age', 'You must be at-least 10 years old!')
        if mood and mood.lower() != 'happy':
           self.add_error('mood', 'Why so serious?')

        return cleaned_data
```

This will raise all errors and at each field, rather than all at the top.
Tested with Django 4.0.4