# How to Raise Multiple ValidationErrors (including custom ones) in Django Serializer Validation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a serializer class that raises a `ValidationError` in the `validate()` method. This `ValidationError` may have multiple error messages for multiple fields which seems to work alright. Some of my fields in the serializer have constraints which will also cause `ValidationErrors` to be raised, such as:

```
start_date = DateField(input_formats=DATE_FORMATS_INPUT, error_messages=DATE_ERRORS)
```

My problem is that when any of the errors caused by some sort of field argument (like having an invalid date format) is raised, the `ValidationError` from my `validate()` method is not raised. I was wondering if there is a way to get all of the ValidationErrors without creating custom validation methods for each field.

The code is similar to this:

```
field1 = serializers.IntegerField(min_value=1)
field2 = serializers.IntegerField()
field3 = serializers.IntegerField()

def validate(self, data):
    err = {}
    if data['field2'] == None and data['field3'] != None:
        err['field2'] = ['Enter a value for this field']
    if data['field3'] == None and data['field2'] != None:
        err['field3'] = ['Enter a value for this field']
    if len(err) > 0:
        raise serializers.ValidationError(err)
    else:
        return data
```

In this code if field1 has a value that is less than 1, a field level error will be raised for it. This prevents a Validation error from being raised for field2 or field3 in validate(). I would like to be able to get errors for field1 and field2/3 at the same time.

Comment: It would help to see your validate() method and how you are currently catching errors

Comment: You should show the whole serializer, in fact.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to raise multiple ValidationError on Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49226763/how-to-raise-multiple-validationerror-on-django)