# How to raise multiple ValidationError in Django

Tags: python, django

I saw this post: [How to raise multiple ValidationError on Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49226763/how-to-raise-multiple-validationerror-on-django)

However I have some questions. In the accepted answer, andilabs writes:

```
    raise ValidationError({
    'field_name_1': ["Field not allowed to change"],
    'field_name_2': ["Field not allowed to change"],
})
```

Do the values have to be in a List even though it is just one string? If so, anyone know why? Or where in the documentation it says so? I have not found it in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/#raising-multiple-errors.

The below code works for me and in my html template I can do {{ form.user.errors }} to have it show up in a div on submission.  For who wants to know what context I am using it in, I am using it in a Form view, and inside it I have a def clean(self) method, where I override the parent clean(). Some code for reference:

```
class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
  user = forms.CharField()
  **the fields and stuff**

  def clean(self):
    error = {}
    cleaned = super().clean()
    if 'user' not in cleaned_data:
      error['user'] = ['Username is empty']
    **check if other fields are not there, check password length minimum, etc.**
    if len(error) != 0:
      raise ValidationError(error)
    return cleaned
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Doctring of the `__init__` method for `ValidationError` in `django.core.exceptions`:

```
    """
    The `message` argument can be a single error, a list of errors, or a
    dictionary that maps field names to lists of errors. What we define as
    an "error" can be either a simple string or an instance of
    ValidationError with its message attribute set, and what we define as
    list or dictionary can be an actual `list` or `dict` or an instance
    of ValidationError with its `error_list` or `error_dict` attribute set.
    """
```

[Link to source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/core/exceptions.py)

Comment: How did you find this?
And when it says "or a dictionary that maps field names to lists of errors". Why is it a list of error? Isn't each field name mapped to just 1 string? So why a list of strings? And is every error just a string?

Comment: I searched on Github but there's also a link with a reference to the source code module in the reference for exceptions https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.ValidationError.

I believe it's that way because a field's errors are accessed with form.errors after clean() is run, so even if there's a single error it's stored as an iterable in a form instance. The code that does this is here https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/forms.py

Comment: How do you search code on github? I can't find a way to search code in a repo. The first link you sent has a link on the page to the code, but on the doc site, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/_modules/django/core/exceptions/#ValidationError, it does not link to the github code.

Comment: @BobtheBuilder You have to navigate to the repo first, start typing into the search bar and the first option in the autocomplete is search in this repository.

Comment: Ah, I see it. So I searched "class AppRegistryNotReady(Exception):" in the repo from your link to the source code: https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/core/exceptions.pyabove but no hits. Why is this?

Comment: No idea, that would be a question for Github. Since we're getting off topic I'm going to assume I answered your initial question